# Get component's height every time it renders

Tags: reactjs, height, components, render

So hey guys, basically I'm using react and I want to get the parent div's height, and make it's child to have the same height, by props. The parent div renders every time the window is resized. I tried using `componentDidMount` and `setState` to get the height of the parent, but `componentDidMount` is called only the first time my parent div renders.

And I can't use `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).clientHeight` inside `render()`function.

To simplify, these are the steps:

- (Everytime) Window is resized
- Div1 gets rendered
- Gets Div1 height and set it state
- Pass it by props to Div2.

Any ideas?

Here's a piece of code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Div2 from './Div2';

    class Div1 extends Component {
      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          height: 0
        };
      }

      componentDidMount() {
      var height = (ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).clientHeight);
      this.setState({height: height})
      }    

      render() { 
         return(    
          <div className='Div1'>    
            <Div2 height={this.state.height}/>   
          </div>    
      );
      }
    }

    export default Div1;
```

Comment: Could you share minimal code to be sure every one understand? You "tried using componentDidMount and setState to get the height of the parent": from div1 or div 2?

Comment: Did you try `shouldComponentUpdate()` https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

Comment: @DamienLeroux i put some code there, thank you. i used from div1

Comment: @DivyanshuMaithani in fact, i didn't know this method, but from a brief read, i still can't get it how to make the update i want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 3 places you have to update your parent's `state` with new height at:

1. `componentDidMount` which will be called after the first `render` (first time parent's `div` will actually appear).
2. `componentDidUpdate` which is called after `render`-ing caused by `props` and `state` updates. You have to do only if you are actually using any `props` and their update can result in `div`'s height change.
3. window resize.

You have to use `refs` to get parent `div`'s DOM element inside `render` method. After that you cat use it in `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` (please, check [React Component Lifecycle](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle) docs).

Combining everything together results in following code, where `Foo` passes it's root div height to `Bar`:

```
class Bar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='bar' style={{height: `${this.props.height / 2 }px`}} />
    );
  };
};

class Foo extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { height: 0 };
    this.updateHeight = this.updateHeight.bind(this);
  }

 componentDidMount() {
   this.updateHeight();
   window.addEventListener("resize", this.updateHeight);
 }

 componentWillUnmount() {
   window.removeEventListener("resize", this.updateHeight);
 }

 componentDidUpdate() {
   this.updateHeight();
 }

 updateHeight() {
   if (this.state.height != this.div.clientHeight)
     this.setState({ height: this.div.clientHeight })
 }

 render() {
    return (
      <div ref={ div => { this.div = div; } } className='foo'>
        <Bar height={this.state.height} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Foo/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Working example could be found [here](https://jsbin.com/nedajox/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: very thanks! this is just what i was looking for! just a question, aren't there any problems using refs?

Comment: Not too many from my experience. Just keep in mind that `this.div` can be `undefined` in case there was some conditional logic in `render` method preventing `<div>` from being the part of returned tree. Also check other caveats of using `refs` in [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)